# Problem on induced maps in cohomology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying the solve the following problem:

Let $g:\mathbb{C}P^\infty\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ and suppose the induced homomorphism

$$g^*:H^2(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)\longrightarrow H^2(\mathbb{C}P^\infty).$$

is a bijection. Show that the induced map on $H^n(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)$ is bijective for all $n$.

My experience with cohomology is still a bit low and I have been trying to proceed just from definitions to solve the problem, but I have not made any progress beyond the fact that we need only check only even dimensions.

I'm not looking for a solution, just hints in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the cohomology *ring structure* of $\mathbb{C}P^n$?

Comment: @chrisgerig yes

Comment: Then how do you get $H^n$ from $H^2$ here? Heard of *naturality*?

Comment: Dear James, I understand what you mean but you should reformulate your question and explain what $n$ is.

Comment: @Chris: I have heard of naturality and I don't see how it applies here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cohomology of $\mathbb CP^\infty$ is given *as a ring* by

$$H^*(\mathbb CP^\infty)=\mathbb Z[T]$$
with $T$ of degree $2$. Homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ correspond to elements in $H^{2d}(\mathbb CP^\infty)$. The map $g^*$ is a ring homomorphism and you know what it does in degree $1$.